# Launch php in python docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, celery

i have a problem with this docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    image: php:7
    command: php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 /app/get_count_of_day.php
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app

  composer:
    restart: 'no'
    image: composer/composer:php7
    command: install
    volumes:
      - .:/app

  python:
    image: python:3
    command: bash -c "pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt && celery worker -l info -A cron --beat --workdir=/app/python"
    links:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - app

  redis:
    image: 'redis:3.0-alpine'
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

My celery task

```
import os


from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.chdir("..")
app = Celery(broker='redis://redis:6379/0')

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, run_cron.s(), name='add every 10')

@app.task
def run_cron():
    os.system("/usr/local/bin/php index.php")
```

My error is php not found

> ```
> python_1    | sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/php: not found
> python_1    | [2018-06-15 15:08:29,491: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task cron.run_cron[e7c338c1-7b9c-4d6f-b607-f4e354fbd623] succeeded in
> ```
>
> 0.003908602000592509s: None
>       python_1    | [2018-06-15 15:08:39,487: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task add every 10 (cron.run_cron)

but if i go manually to docker with

> docker exec -i -t 1ff /bin/bash

i found php in directory

Answer (score 0):

Binaries from container "app" are not exposed in container "python", this is docker's MO. To run `index.php` script you can jus  open this page via http request: `curl http://app/index.php` or do the same entirely in python via `urllib2` or `requests` (I recommend the last option).

But in case your request fails because it can't find the `app` domain - original answer below is your solution.

In case you have to perform more complicated operations inside the `app` container you should really think about exposing them through internal API or something like that, but as I understand it, docker containers should do one thing and one thing only. If you need to run some complex shell script in your php container - you are breaking this principle. `app` container is for serving php pages, so it should do exactly that.

As a last resort, you can totally hack on docker, for example exposing docker control socket inside your celery container and issuing commands to other containers directly. This can be really dangerous and heavily discouraged in the docs, but you do you ;)

[EDIT: originally misread question...]

In default docker network you can't address containers by name. Add

```
networks:
    my-net:
```

to the end of docker-compose and

```
networks:
    - my-net
```

to every container that needs to talk with each other.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, I didn't read your error correctly... the problem is that php binary is inside "app" container, and celery job runs inside "python" container. Unfortunately you can't execute commands in other containers without totally breaking docker sematics.